# Export SSH public key attribute from AD

Tags: windows, powershell

I need your help to get a PowerShell command to export the SSH pubic key attribute through PowerShell.

The following command is not working for me

```
 Get-ADUser tanner.kerr | select SamAccountName,sshPublicKeys | export-csv -path C:\Users\abhishek.jayanth\Desktop\newssh.csv
```

Comment: You say it is't working, but **how** is it failing?  The fact that the `sshPublicKeys` looks suspicious since you are exporting to CSV, but without more details about what errors you have, it is hard to make any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes you've extended the AD Schema for sshPublicKeys and its stored as a Multi-value property.

```
 Get-ADUser tanner.kerr -Properties sshPublicKeys | Select-Object SamAccountName, @{name="sshPublicKeys";expression={ $_.sshPublicKeys -join ";"}} | Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\a bhishek.jayanth\Desktop\newssh.csv
```